# Pointing Domain to VPS

Tags: domains, dns, vps

I'm trying to point my domain name that's registered through HostGator to my Windows VPS registered through GoDaddy. I'm using Plesk 11 as my Control Panel.

I was reading this article from GoDaddy: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8463/setting-up-dns-with-your-parallels-plesk-panel-11-server-and-domain-with-us?pc_split_value=4

I have set the nameservers up on my VPS:

[image: dns]

What I don't understand is why I need to register my domain with two domain hosts. When I try to put the nameservers above as my domain nameservers in Hostgator, is gives the following error:

[image: domain]

I'm not sure if this is just because of propagation not being complete, or if it's a configuration error on my end. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not very familiar with DNS.

Comment: That was a guest account I can't login into it anymore. @Fahad Did I not already "register" the nameservers when I set the record type as 'NS' in my Plesk DNS Settings, and there's A records that have the ip of my VPS, and the ns1.domain, ns2.domain. Is there something I'm missing? When I check the whois of my nameservers, they don't show up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using private name servers. To use private name servers you need to register private name servers through your domain control panel. There may be an option in your domain control panel to create name servers in which you will have to define the ip of your vps against NS1 & NS2.YourDomain.Com